# Actionscript(AIR) Cant return FB access_token from HTMLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, facebook-graph-api, air, facebook-access-token

Im simply trying to get my users access token from FB using HTMLLoader. When i trace the output from the location change event all i get are Google/FB urls, none of which have the token.

**Here is my code:**

```
var loader:HTMLLoader;

function onChange(e:Event):void {
    if(loader.location.indexOf("#") != -1) {
        trace("Found token");
    }else {
        trace(loader.location);
    }
}

function connectFb() {
    loader = new HTMLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.LOCATION_CHANGE, onChange);
    loader.width = 640;
    loader.height = 480;
    loader.load(new URLRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?  
    client_id=1234567890123456&redirect_uri=http://google.com&type=user_agent"));
}
```

**My Codes output:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=164534120383085&redirect_uri=http://google.com&type=user_agent
http://www.google.com/
```

I tried every tutorial on the net and even bought a book on AS3 facebook dev & still cant figure this out; Any help would be VERY appreciated since this is a fairly important project to me

Comment: Well try using the URL directly in a browser (outside of flash) - when I go to "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1234567890123456&redirect_uri=http://google.com&type=user_agent", I get an error message: ""Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error."  So, that should be your starting point of investigation.  Contact facebook for support, or at least look through their API documentation.

Comment: Thats because i put a fake application ID for security reasons, If i use my real app id in my browser everything works fine. Your help is appreciated though

Comment: Ah - my bad.  I'll make a more complete answer now...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're trying to retrieve an oauth access token from the facebook API, right?  That's what you're expecting to get back from that URL?  Correct me if I'm wrong, but HTMLLoader is for (unsurprisingly) loading HTML content.  If you're expecting HTML content (ie, an 'authorize' page from FB), then you need to add the HTMLLoader to the display list with:

```
addChild(loader); // where 'loader' is an instance of HTMLLoader
```

On the other hand, if you were expecting just the token (and not HTML content), then you should be using [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html), and not HTMLLoader.

Comment: Its strange that all the examples use HTMLLoader, but I will try that when i get home

Comment: Attempted like EVERY different implementation of the URLRequest class but to no avail. This is really turning into a pain

Comment: Before anything else, you need to know what to expect back from the facebook API (a token, or html content showing a form that allows the user to opt in).  If what you're expecting is the latter (which it sounds like it is, as you mentioned that all the examples use HTMLLoader), then focus on getting that to work.  Have you tried using your code above, but with my suggestion of adding the loader to the display list?  If you want to use URLLoader, then you have to use it with the appropriate facebook API.   If you go down that road and still have no luck, post it as a new question.